# I had this error: Error 2 Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'johny.Form1.CoOrds' is less accessible than method 'johny.Form1.toto()

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

```
class CoOrds
{
    public int x, y;

    public CoOrds() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    public CoOrds(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

public CoOrds toto() {
    CoOrds B = new CoOrds(3, 2);
    return B;
}

private void result_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    l6.Text = "";
    CoOrds D = new CoOrds();
    D = toto();
    l6.Text = "(" + D.x + "," + D.y + ")";
}
```

I get following error:

`Error 2 Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'johny.Form1.CoOrds' is less accessible than method 'johny.Form1.toto()`

Comment: Fast? That's inappropriate. You are asking for help and dictating deadlines that are yours, is rude.

Comment: @CRDave I edited out the "please help me fast" part for a reason. It is my understanding that we do not use "thanks" or "help me quick" on this site.

Comment: @CC Inc you are right but I have not change your update. I get notification after I submit my change.

Comment: this first time i use this site ... i saw u will answer me tomorrow so i asked u to help me urgently ! thats all ... anyway thanks for the person who answers me :)

Comment: @user1951045 It is specified nowhere that there are timescales on answering, if somebody can help you when they visit this question, it's likely that they will put in an answer. There's no need for "plz help me" or "thx in advance" etc, this site should be seen more as a "Here's my problem" with responses of "Here's the solution".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You'll find you do better on a question-and-answer site when you *ask a question*. "I got this error message" is not a question, it's a statement of fact. Do you want us to guess what your question is? In this case it is not hard to guess, but *don't make it harder on the people doing the answering*. Always ask a clear question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As your `CoOrds` class is nested within `Form1`, it is by default `private` (ie. for use only within the `Form1` class). The easiest solution would be to make your `CoOrds` class `public`.

```
public class CoOrds{ 

public int x, y; // ...
```

Another alternative would be to simply un-nest the `CoOrds` class, namely, move the declaration of the class outside of your `Form1` class entirely.

Comment: Making it non-nested isn't a complete alternative in itself - you'd *still* need to make it public unless Form1 is internal.

Answer (score 2):

**Original answer** (before I noticed that it's a nested type)

Yes - presumably `Form1` and `Form1.toto()` are both public - whereas `Coords` is `private` (the default accessibility for non-nested types). You can't create a method with a return type or parameter type which isn't accessible to all the code which can see the method - it doesn't make sense.

Options:

- Make `Form1` internal
- Make `Form1.toto()` internal
- Make `Coords` public

Personally I'd recommend making `Form1` internal if you can - it's rare that a form needs to be available to other code, beyond unit tests (for which I'd use `InternalsVisibleTo`). Making `Form1.toto()` internal would be equally fine. I prefer to keep types and members as private as I can, so I'd only make `Coords` public as a last resort.

I'd *also* strongly recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions, and provide more informative names than `toto()`. Oh, and avoid public fields - expose properties instead. You may well want to make it immutable, too.

**Having noticed that it's a nested type...**

It actually looks like `Coords` is a *nested* class within `Form1`, which will mean it's *private* by default. It's unusual to want to expose a nested class - and it doesn't look like it's really tightly tied to `Form1` anyway. I would suggest making it a top-level (non-nested) type in the first place.